# Parallel programming in python, offload to GPU

Tags: python, parallel-processing, anaconda, gpu

I'm writing scientific python code containing lots of very parallelizable for-loops in my opinion.
In these loops **I call a lot of functions belonging to classes from an opensource python2.7 library**, thus it would not be feasible to move to another language. Unless it can be interfaced with python.
I have two different codes ->

1. Calls C-binaries* in innermost loop which is the bottle neck as it can only use one thread, then writes the results to disk.
2. Calls Open-source C PyObject-functions** in innermost loop, saves in ndarray, writes to disk in an outer-loop

**Is it possible to make for-loop offload in any of these to the gpu?** (nVidia GTX gpu)
Eg. using OpenACC(Anaconda)/PGI, PyCUDA or PyOpenCL or even OpenCV ?

(*Dependend on a path to store GBs of temp data eg. $HOME/tmp/)
(**Less parallelizable as they depend on previous iteration..)

Input is CT images -> 3d np.arrays of signed int16 values

I have eight CPU threads which I am able to use fully with multiprocessing.pool however my GPU is doing nothing. Assume 8 GB RAM, using < 2 GB. Using Arch-Linux.

PS. I'm open for suggestions in hardware upgrade -> I'm in cancer research which makes funding possible.

Comment: Something like that maybe ? :http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/numbapro-high-performance-python-cuda-acceleration/

Comment: I have tried to use numbapro, however it does not support parsing classes even with just the @jit decorator. But thanks for the suggestion.